# Is there a categorical characterization of differentiation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, category-theory

Is there a universal property that singles out differentiation as an arrow $f:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "differentiation"? In general a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is not differentiable with respect to the "usual" derivation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "differentiation map" $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, since $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ contains all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

However, there is a differentiation map $d : C^{\infty}(U) \to C^{\infty}(U), f \mapsto f'$ for open subsets $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. It is the unique map with $d(1)=1$ and which is a *derivation*, i.e. an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map satisfying the Leibniz rule $d(fg)=f d(g) + g d(g)$. This is connected to the statement that $\Omega^1_{C^{\infty}(U)/\mathbb{R}}$ is free of rank $1$, which is the following universal property: If $M$ is some $C^{\infty}(U)$-module and $m \in M$ is some element, then there is a unique derivation $C^{\infty}(U) \to M$ mapping $1 \mapsto m$.

Comment: How do we know that $d$ acts on non-polynomials correctly?

Comment: @ZhenLin: This is a good question. While writing my answer, I vaguely recalled some trick involving bump functions. But I don't know the details. Perhaps I'm even wrong. Hopefully someone can clarify this!

Comment: There was an MO question about Kähler differentials of smooth functions. The conclusion was that it doesn't work for non-polynomials.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derivation#derivations_of_smooth_functions